# Well-phrased Suggestions for Editing

Tags: feature-request, comment

When I see a question that is not posed well or not written in MathJax, I try to give the OP suggestions on how to improve the question (such as providing context or showing work).

I'd like to suggest a collection of stock, easily accessible, and generic suggestions that can be provided to the OP for common problems with questions.  This might make it easy to provide feedback that is both polite and helpful (especially for non-native English speakers).

Comment: If you have concrete suggestions, [post them in that thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates). You may also be interested in what's already there.